# JavaScript recursive Element creation fails

Tags: javascript, recursion

I don't understand why this fails:

```
var recursiveElementGenerator = function (elem_spec) {
    elem = document.createElement(elem_spec.tag);

    if (elem_spec.children) {
        for (var i=0; i<elem_spec.children.length; i++) {
            var c_elem = elem_spec.children[i];
            var n_elem = recursiveElementGenerator(c_elem);
            alert(elem===n_elem);
            elem.appendChild(n_elem);
        };
    };
    return elem;
};
```

The `elem_spec` object has tag and children attributes, the latter being an array of similar objects.

This fails because the element returned by the recursive call is the same as the element created before that recursive call.  Which I don't get -- a similar version works, by getting its chain of tag values from a pop() call on an array that is then passed into the recursive call.

Comment: I would take a look at the `elem_spec` argument. Can you post a sample of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
var elem = document.createElement(elem_spec.tag);
```

instead of:

```
elem = document.createElement(elem_spec.tag);
```

Not using the `var` keyword makes your variable operate on the global scope. Using it will create the variable in the local scope, from the line it's created to the end of your function definition.

Comment: +1 good catch! The global variable has been used in the recursive calls. That is why `n_elem` always point to the same object as the `elem` global variable.

Comment: Yep, that's a d'oh moment -- thanks -- I tried to upvote / accept this morning but stackoverflow was in some glitch moment that wouldn't take my inputs