# Why is this recursive algorithm in JS not working?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I made this simple algorithm, but Chrome is acting weird, almost like functions called recursively don't return... Algorithm's task is to cycle trough all the possibilities of the `rs` array, which has three elements which can be either 0 or 1.

```
//rs is the list of all variables that can be 0 or 1
//cS, or currentStack is the variable that s

rs = [0, 0, 0];

circ = function(cS)
{
     for (pos = 0; pos <= 1; pos ++)
     {
          rs[cS] = pos;
          if (cS + 1 < rs.length)
               circ(cS + 1);
     }
     return 0;                    
}

circ(0); //this should cycle trough all the possibilities of the rs array, it should look like this:
/*
000 - first element of rs, not last, so continue to the next
000 - second element of rs, not last, so continue to the next
000 - third element of rs, last, so continue with the for loop
001 - the for loop ends, return to the second element
011 - second element of rs, not last, so continue to the next
010 - third element of rs, last, so continue with the for loop
011 - the for loop ends, return to the first element
111 - first element of rs, not last, so continue to the next
101 - second element of rs, not last, so continue to the next
100 - third element of rs, last, so continue with the for loop
101 - the for loop ends, return to the second element
111 - second element of rs, not last, so continue to the next
110 - third element of rs, last, so continue with the for loop
111 - the for loop ends, return to the second element
111 - the for loop ends, return to the first element
111 - return
*/
```

However, it simply goes like this:

```
000
000
000
001
return
```

Can anyone tell me why is this happening? What did I do wrong?

Comment: What do you want to end up with? You're overwriting the elements of `rs` each time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript recursive Element creation fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333572/javascript-recursive-element-creation-fails)

Comment: This seems a really odd way to cycle through the possibly combinations: wouldn't a nested for loop do the trick in a much more readable way? Even the desired output in the comment at the end of your code seems a bit strange because you've got lots of repeated values. Why does your function return 0 when you don't use the return at all?

Comment: Well, this is a simplified version... In the real one, it's not just 0's and 1's but other numbers too, and the there are 15 elements of rs, not just three... This is the first thing I came up with, do you have a better solution? This is very slow, and yes, repeats things (although functions correctly).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to declare "pos" with `var`.

```
var circ = function(cS)
{
     for (var pos = 0; pos <= 1; pos ++)
     {
          rs[cS] = pos;
          if (cS + 1 < rs.length)
               circ(cS + 1);
     }
     return 0;                    
}
```

Because you forgot `var`, "pos" was global, so the recusive calls would mess up the parent environment.

I can't guarantee that's the only problem here. For example in the function as written it may iterate through all the permutations, but it doesn't show them or copy them anywhere, so the end result will just be `[1, 1, 1]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had previous difficulties with the global scope and not declaring variables with the var keyword... Should I do function(var cS) as well? Kinda like in C++, where you have to initialize the funtion's argumenta. Oh yeah, and this is just the simplified version, in the actual one I do do stuff with these permutations, and it's not just 0's and 1's but other numbers as well.

Comment: No, JavaScript doesn't require keywords for parameters. If you're just starting with JS, a good introduction is the free book Eloquent JavaScript: http://eloquentjavascript.net/

Comment: @bane parameters are *always* like local variables (though in some arcane ways they're not *exactly* like local variables).

Comment: That's good! I'm gonna test it now and tell you if it works, it probably will. Can you tell me of these strange arcane ways? I'm very interested in the very nature and behaviour of programming languages and I like learning about new concepts :)

Comment: @bane well I'm not as expert as some; it very rarely matters. What I do know is that in some weird way, parameters and the (also somewhat weird) `arguments` pseudo-variable are references to the same memory. Thus if you've got a parameter "a" as the first parameter, changes to "a" are reflected in `arguments[0]` and vice-versa.  Like I said, it's really rare that you have to worry about that.

Comment: Oh, OK, I think I understand. JS is by far the most interesting language to me, yet! Also, it works great now, the only problem is that the page dies... There are 15 "stacks" (elements or rs) and they can get up to 20... So that's 20^15 combinations, I should have never even bothered trying it. Well, I might move it to a server and write it better, instead of having it run in a browser, maybe it'll work then.